# Inserting 0s for dates currently without data, after a key's first appearance

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, insert-update

I've got a table that looks something like the following

| Date | Key | Metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-31 | A | 6 |
| 2021-02-28 | A | 3 |
| 2021-05-31 | A | 3 |
| 2021-03-31 | B | 4 |
| 2021-04-30 | B | 1 |
| 2021-05-31 | B | 2 |

What I'd like to do is insert a row with a metric of 0 for Key A for the date of 2021-03-31, since Key A had already appeared in January in February.

Key B, on the other hand, would ideally stay untouched since it has metrics associated with every date after its appearance.  (The table I'm working with happens to be monthly, but I'm sure I could make the changes to make a daily solution work here)

So, Ideally we'd end up with a table looking like the following

| Date | Key | Metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-31 | A | 6 |
| 2021-02-28 | A | 3 |
| **2021-03-31** | **A** | **0** |
| **2021-04-30** | **A** | **0** |
| 2021-05-31 | A | 3 |
| 2021-03-31 | B | 4 |
| 2021-04-30 | B | 1 |
| 2021-05-31 | B | 2 |

That's all for now, thank you very much everyone

Comment: as mysql has npo sequence, you need to build a table with all dates and join it

Comment: Show the result of: `SELECT version();`  ... You can derive the list of dates to drive which rows to insert.  A simple `INSERT ... WITH ... SELECT ...` could do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle for MySQL 8.0+](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f51b0259185bffad428bf6e7fb7bc674)

There are various ways to do this.  The following assumes MySQL 8.0 or better, but less convenient solutions exist for versions prior to this.

The following assumes `(xkey, xdate)` is `unique` or the `primary key` of our table.

| CTE term | Description |
| --- | --- |
| cte1 | Determine the range of dates in our full sequence |
| cte2 | Generate the full list of last dates in each month of the range |
| cte3 | Generate a list of `(xkey, MIN(xdate))` pairs |
| Final | Now generate every potential new row to insert |

The `INSERT IGNORE` only inserts rows which do not already exist, based on the primary key.  If a constraint violation would occur, `IGNORE` will skip that row.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO test
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 (min_date, max_date) AS (
       SELECT MIN(xdate) AS min_date
            , MAX(xdate) AS max_date
         FROM test
     )
   , cte2 (xdate, max_date) AS (
       SELECT min_date, max_date FROM cte1
        UNION ALL
       SELECT LAST_DAY(xdate + INTERVAL 5 DAY), max_date
         FROM cte2 WHERE xdate < max_date
     )
   , cte3 (xkey, xdate) AS (
       SELECT xkey, MIN(xdate) FROM test GROUP BY xkey
     )
SELECT cte2.xdate, xkey, 0 FROM cte2 JOIN cte3 ON cte3.xdate < cte2.xdate
;


SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY xkey, xdate;

+------------+------+--------+
| xdate      | xkey | metric |
+------------+------+--------+
| 2021-01-31 | A    |      6 |
| 2021-02-28 | A    |      3 |
| 2021-03-31 | A    |      0 |
| 2021-04-30 | A    |      0 |
| 2021-05-31 | A    |      3 |
| 2021-03-31 | B    |      4 |
| 2021-04-30 | B    |      1 |
| 2021-05-31 | B    |      2 |
+------------+------+--------+
```

The setup:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( xdate date, xkey varchar(10), metric int, primary key (xdate, xkey) );


INSERT INTO test VALUES
  ( '2021-01-31', 'A', 6 )
, ( '2021-02-28', 'A', 3 )
, ( '2021-05-31', 'A', 3 )
, ( '2021-03-31', 'B', 4 )
, ( '2021-04-30', 'B', 1 )
, ( '2021-05-31', 'B', 2 )
;
```